# Suggestions on REST API & Software Architecture Style

Tags: php, rest, oop, architecture, software-design

**First of all i am student, so i need to know how compounds Interact with each other, Maybe next time in the future i will do it with a framework, but first thing I need to do is knowing how to build the software form scratch.**

---

My project will be web and mobile application so I decided to create a rest api for both... I will implement my project in Native PHP.

- **What is the best practice for software architecture style?**
  but I don’t know what is the best practice software architecture for my rest api Multitiered(mvc, mvp, Or even something else like (model view controller data access))


  my idea about Multitiered(model view controller data access)

```
class Controller
{
    public $view;
    public $model;
    public $dataAccess;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new View();
        $this->model = new Model();
        $this->dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    }
}
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model->tableName = "users";
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        if($id) 
        {
            $this->model->data = $this->dataAccess->selectById($this->model->tableName, $id);
            $this->view->render($this->model->data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->view->renderError();
        }
        
    }
}
class Application 
{
    private function __construct()
    {}
    
    public static function run() 
    {
        $router = new Router();
        $router->get("/users/([0-9]+)", array("UserController", "get"));
        $router->run();
    }
}
```

- **What about the file structure ?**

  **app/**

  The app directory contains our rest-api components like controllers, views, models, data access.

  **core/**

  The directory contains the Router class and the basic classes

  **Bootstrap/**

  The directory contains the application.php file which bootstraps the framework by run function and autoload.php file which automatically loading PHP files.

  **storage/**

  logs, file caches, and user-generated files.
- **What about authentication and authorization?**


  Will I need an extra layer for my architecture, model-view-controller-data access-(middleware or router)


  How will the rest api interact with other layers?
  For example, does the (middleware or router) layer interact with the controller then controller interact with data access layer for every authentication and authorization process

I will attach a simple implementation of the current phase to review my thoughts.

https://github.com/mahmoudahmedd/i-am-asking-for-feedback

Any other comments I would be grateful, Finally thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great solution: learn on base applications of top frameworks.

- Class Model work with DataAccess inside model
- Models must extends Model
- Controllers contain 'action...' methods to wrap model methods: 'actionGet', 'actionCreate', 'actionDelete' and etc. Route: `namespace/controller/action`, for example: `api/user/get` call `Controller\Api\User::actionGet()`.

For example: https://github.com/koseven/koseven/blob/devel/system/classes/KO7/Controller.php ,
https://github.com/koseven/koseven/blob/devel/system/classes/KO7/Controller/Template.php

Comment: Great suggestion... I really was thinking that learn on base applications of top frameworks.

But I have a problem
When I download a specific framework(laravel for example) There will be files that are not visible (router implementation, etc)... I don't know if you have a solution

Comment: "files that are not visible" what's you mean? You need a app barebone, not a specific app based on it.

Comment: for example.... Illuminate\Routing\Router (https://github.com/laravel/laravel)  Where is the implementation code?

Comment: You don't work with Composer before? https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md In common case you need framework + app, github.com/laravel/laravel - it's only app

Comment: really thank you... 
I will try and follow this pattern :)

Comment: You can see Kohana3 / CodeIgniter4 for begining, they have legacy code but easy than Laravel

Comment: Kohana docs https://koseven.dev/documentation/kohana/mvc/controllers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224634/discussion-between-wintersilence-and-mahmoud-ahmed).

Comment: Thank you again
Do you have any social media accounts? (linkedIn,  Facebook, etc)
 i think it will be better

Comment: You can use chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224634/discussion-between-wintersilence-and-mahmoud-ahmed , I rarely visit FB